WordPress Mixed content on wp-content/theme path
I have added SSL certificate to a WordPress website and modified all the links in the admin page and database, but it still complains about mixed content. It can't find files under the wp-content/theme path because it tries to access them over HTTP. I think get_template_directory_uri() is returning the wrong URL, but I don't know why.

Could you please check you have correctly set up WordPress Address and Site Address URL in the Settings > General, as you can check in the screenshot. https://ibb.co/9VDVMGC

Also please try to reset permalink by going to Settings > Permalink and please inspect the page where you are getting this error and try to find the link with the issue.

At last, I discovered the issue. The previous website was functioning, and the WAF redirected all requests to this legacy site on port 80.

Glad to know your issue has been resolved.
